# View Model cannot implicitly convert type System.Generic.Type.List<AssetViewModel> to System.Generic.Type.List<LUT_Asset_Masters>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics

I made a view model and wrote a LINQ query to join tables but I get this error. I spent two days to figure out with no success. Saw similar questions and made changes but could not solve the error in LINquery.
 My view Model is as shown

```
  public class AssetViewModel

 {
        public string AG { get; set; }
    public string CC { get; set; }
    public string CS { get; set; }
    public string Mnf { get; set; }

 }
```

My Function

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindCS();
        BindCC();
     BindAG();
        List<LUT_Assets_Masters> dt = this.GetData();
                  rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
        rptMarkers.DataBind();
    }
}

   private List<LUT_Assets_Masters> GetData()
{
    AssetTaggingEntities context = new AssetTaggingEntities();
    List<LUT_Assets_Masters> am1 = null;

     if (DDSearch.SelectedValue == "1" && DDStatus.SelectedIndex > 0 && DDCondition.SelectedIndex > 0 && DDGroup.SelectedIndex > 0)

   {
        am1 = (from am in context.LUT_Assets_Masters
               where am.CSID == DDStatus.SelectedIndex
                     && am.CCID == DDCondition.SelectedIndex
                     && am.AGrpID == DDGroup.SelectedIndex
               select am).ToList();
    }
  else
    {
        am1 = (from am in context.LUT_Assets_Masters
              join grp in context.LUT_Asset_Groups on am.AGrpID equals grp.AGrpID
              join cc in context.LUT_Current_Condition on am.CCID equals cc.CCID
              join cs in context.LUT_Current_Status on am.CSID equals cs.CSID
              join mn in context.LUT_Asset_Manufacturers on am.MnfID equals mn.MnfID
              select new AssetViewModel
              {
                  AG = grp.Asset_Groups,
                  CC = cc.Current_Condition,
                  CS = cs.Current_Status,
                  Mnf = mn.Asset_Manufacturer
              }).ToList();
    }
           return am1;

}
```

Comment: i have tried returning AssetViewModel list also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `select` query operator is selecting objects of type `AssetViewModel`, then `ToList()` turns the returned `IEnumerable<AssetViewModel>` into a `List<AssetViewModel>` which you're then trying to assign to `am1` but that list contains objects of type `LUT_Assets_Masters` hence the error, so you might either have to change the `select` query operator to select objects of type `LUT_Assets_Masters` or change the list to hold objects of type `AssetViewModel`.

Comment: What? I need the members of list Asset Masters and the Asset View Model. Can you explain in the code? Why the downvote may I ask  @Aomine

Comment: @ARUS well you can't assign a list of type `List<AssetViewModel>` to a type `List<LUT_Assets_Masters>`. read my answer again as that's the only two options you have.  I didn't downvote you...

Comment: I read your answer but  I wanted data from Asset Masters also. What do you think will be appropriate to do since I need Data from both. Ill update my code. Thanks for helping me out. Can you show me the right way to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me through this but actually if condition also needs this join query. What I actually m trying is to get the value of dropdowns which are in Groups and Condition tables while the other details are in Asset Masters table. So I need both the values in javascript. So I tried View Model. How to include the join in if statement?

Comment: I figured it out it was the same problem as you told Thank you